# a bunch of user inputs (like a recipe), how can I skip to a line?

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a code as a "checklist" for something that is to be made.
each line is basically:

```
a0=int(input(f'do step one, then enter 1 to cont')
a1=int(input(f'do step two, then enter 1 to cont')
```

So, how can I skip to line a4 (or a(n) ) and continue from there?

My thoughts were to define each line and store each variable in a list. Then use a while loop to start from wherever. I just can't figure out how to eh, this is where I lose it. I guess I'm trying to convert the string to a variable name, to define it from there. See below:

```
ail=len(ai) #where ai=[a0,a1,a2..]
a=0    #i would input a as any val.
while a in range (0,ail):

    b=(f'a{a}') #this line would determine the "instruction line" to start from.
    exec("%s = %d" % (b,b)) #this is the line that names a var from a string
    b0=int(input(f'{b}'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use dictionary instead of list. you can access the elements of dictionary using keys and that is going to help you pick a specific spot to traverse from.

[Dictionary keys](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp)

Comment: thank you. this does not help. I am looking for a way to return to line n of instructions say from n=0 to n=20. and continue from that point.

Comment: hello agian, I may have been mean, sorry. if a dictionary is created and enumerated using a for x in dict1: is there a following statement that would execute the (nth) value (in the dictionary)

Comment: @MarlonD.Alessandra , Assuming you want to execute some instructions at n? Yes you can create multiple functions, save them in a dictionary and execute them later on using key. you can read this article for better understanding [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-store-function-as-dictionary-value/)

Comment: right, it just seems like people automatically see list, and go ---> "dictionary is better". I need the data in order, and start at n... really difficult, cus it's like keeping a whole script in a dictionary, but just starting from line n.

Comment: I feel your pain but unfortunately python does not support goto statements etc, however another solution in my opinion is, let the user set value of "a" and your loop will start from wherever he wants it to. For instance your user wants to start at instruction 7 then he will just have to pass 7 and your loop will automatically go to that statement. (1 based indexing), Similarly do the maths for 0 based indexing @MarlonD.Alessandra

Comment: ugh. okay thanks. I'll keep searching for a solution. i don't accept can't. sorry for coming out hot. but I guess the answer was there first! ha ha ha.